# Display Azure OCR output in logic order / reading-direction

Tags: python, json, azure, ocr

I've an Azure OCR Output as result of this JSON read-script (Microsoft template code):

```
# Extract the word bounding boxes and text.
line_infos = [region["lines"] for region in analysis["regions"]]
word_infos = []
for line in line_infos:
    for word_metadata in line:
        for word_info in word_metadata["words"]:
            word_infos.append(word_info)
word_infos
```

Output:

```
{'boundingBox': '183,73,624,102', 'text': 'This'},
{'boundingBox': '851,100,160,67', 'text': 'person'},
{'boundingBox': '1052,109,448,97', 'text': 'plays.'},
...
```

The Problem:
These three words belong originally to one line on the scanned document but have different bounding boxes in Azure OCR output. Can I adjust the bounding box thereshold within the OCR service? Or is there a neat helper function to analyze the bounding box coordinates in order to snap nearest-neighbors together?

Requested output would be:

```
{'boundingBox': 'xxx,xx,xxx,xxx', 'text': 'This person plays.'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are already getting the line info.

```
line_infos = [region["lines"] for region in analysis["regions"]]
```

For instance, I have taken this [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/af/Atomist_quote_from_Democritus.png/338px-Atomist_quote_from_Democritus.png) for the OCR.

[image]

The below is the output  for the `line_infos`

```
[{'boundingBox': '28,16,288,41', 'words': [{'boundingBox': '28,16,288,41', 'text': 'NOTHING'}]}, {'boundingBox': '27,66,283,52', 'words': [{'boundingBox': '27,66,283,52', 'text': 'EXISTS'}]}, {'boundingBox': '27,128,292,49', 'words': [{'boundingBox': '27,128,292,49', 'text': 'EXCEPT'}]}, {'boundingBox': '24,188,292,54', 'words': [{'boundingBox': '24,188,292,54', 'text': 'ATOMS'}]}, {'boundingBox': '22,253,297,32', 'words': [{'boundingBox': '22,253,105,32', 'text': 'AND'}, {'boundingBox': '144,253,175,32', 'text': 'EMPTY'}]}, {'boundingBox': '21,298,304,60', 'words': [{'boundingBox': '21,298,304,60', 'text': 'SPACE.'}]}, {'boundingBox': '26,387,294,37', 'words': [{'boundingBox': '26,387,210,37', 'text': 'Everything'}, {'boundingBox': '249,389,71,27', 'text': 'else'}]}, {'boundingBox': '127,431,198,36', 'words': [{'boundingBox': '127,431,31,29', 'text': 'is'}, {'boundingBox': '172,431,153,36', 'text': 'opinion.'}]}]
```

Let's take a closer at the output for "Everthing else" from the image as they are in the same line :

```
{'boundingBox': '26,387,294,37', 'words': [{'boundingBox': '26,387,210,37', 'text': 'Everything'}, {'boundingBox': '249,389,71,27', 'text': 'else'}]}
```

They are already grouped at the line level and you will have to extract it accordingly.
The below is the sample of the modified code to extract it at line level :

```
line_num = 0 
for line in line_infos:
    for word_metadata in line:
        word_infos = []
        line_num +=1
        for word_info in word_metadata["words"]:
            word_infos.append(word_info["text"])
        print(line_num)
        print (word_infos)
```

**Output of the Snippet :**

[image]

Comment: @jakhaf - Wanted to drop in and check whether the above helped ?